# Atomic conditional update in RethinkDB

Tags: c#, concurrency, rethinkdb, upsert, atomic

RethinkDB gives us some [atomicity guarantees under certain conditions](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/consistency/). I'm trying to take advantage of it using a revision field to implement optimistic concurrency (c#). The idea is that if the data has been modified while the client was editing his own revision, the update should fail. New entries should be inserted.

```
var id = "some unique id";
var rev = "the old known revision";
var doc = new {id, Revision = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")};
var result = await R.Db("test").Table("table")
    .Get(id)
    .Replace(found => 
        R.Branch(
            found.Eq(null), doc,
            found["Revision"].Eq(rev), doc,
            found
        )
    ).RunResultAsync(connection);
```

The above code **seems** to work for this purpose but I'm wondering if it indeed will eliminate the race conditions for tight concurrent access. In other words, is this update/insert or upsert atomic? Please guide me to some documentation if possible.

The documentation speaks of a *check-and-set register* (which may as well be CAS, the compare and swap) that I don't find as helpful to explain which operations are actually atomic and how can we guarantee it (for instance using integration tests).

I get the impression that if the following criteria are met:

- write_acks: majority
- durability: hard
- read_mode: majority

And if the write does not involve secondary queries or other documents, then the write is atomic. There is too much faith in there to my liking, those ifs. I'd prefer if there was a flag or something that the operation MUST be atomic, otherwise nuke it. Well until then, can I believe my impression?
There's [confusion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634756/481812) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample query is atomic. It is atomic because it modifies a single document using `Replace`. If it modified multiple documents, the whole query would not be atomic, but the modifications to each document would be separate atomic operations.

There is a flag to `Replace`, `nonAtomic`, which defaults to true. Unless you pass the `nonAtomic` argument to `Replace`, the function passed to `Replace` will be performed atomically.

There is no whole-query `atomic` or `nonAtomic` flag.

RethinkDB will throw an error when you try to perform non-deterministic operations atomically:

> Could not prove argument deterministic.  Maybe you want to use the non_atomic flag?

The [documentation you linked to](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/consistency/) mentions that:

> To read and modify a document in a single atomic operation, use the update or replace commands.

The check-and-set register is just an example of an operation that can be performed atomically. It also serves to illustrate the caveats of atomic operations: only the function passed to `Replace` or `Update` is atomic. The surrounding query isn't, for example `Filter` or `GetAll`.

> RethinkDB operations are never atomic across multiple keys

Reading the [discussion you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31634756/481812), the confusion seems to stem from an error in the documentation. It used to say

> If <strike>the user runs a query that</strike> cannot be executed atomically, by default RethinkDB will throw an error.

But was corrected to say

> If **an update or replace query** cannot be executed atomically, by default RethinkDB will throw an error

See also [How does the atomicity model work?](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/architecture/)

> Write atomicity is supported on a per-document basis – updates to a single JSON document are guaranteed to be atomic. RethinkDB is different from other NoSQL systems in that atomic document updates aren’t limited to a small subset of possible operations – **any combination of operations that can be performed on a single document is guaranteed to update the document atomically**.